# CODEIGNITER .javascript,PHP , IF ELSE on php echo to show on stock image

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

Basically, I want to put a logo on the status column that will show an image whenever the `stock====1` and vice versa. I know I will use an if else but I don't know how will I put it on the PHP echo. This is my table view.

[image: Item List Table]

View code:

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">ADMIN ITEM LIST</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">

                    <br />
                     <a href="<?= base_url().'item/itemadd' ?>"> <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="add_person()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add ITEM </button>

                    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="reload_table()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> Reload</button> </a>
                    <br />
                    <br />

                    <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>NAME</th>
                        <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
                        <th>SERIAL NUMBER</th>
                        <th>ACTION</th>
                                <th style="width:150px;">STATUS</th>
                            </tr>

            <?php
                    foreach($items as $row) { 


                        echo '<tr class="active" height="60px">';
                        echo '<td >' . $row->item_id . '</td>';
                        echo '<td width="200px">' . $row->item_name . '</td>';
                        echo '<td width="200px">' . $row->item_description . '</td>';
                        echo '<td width="200px">' . $row->serial_number . '</td>';



                        echo '<td >' . '<a href="'.base_url().'item/viewitemadmin/'.$row->item_id.'"><h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="View Item"></span></a>' . ' ';
                        echo '<a href="'.base_url().'item/edititem/'.$row->item_id.'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit Item"></span></a>' . ' ';
                        echo '<a href="'.base_url().'item/item_delete/'.$row->item_id.'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Item"></span></a>' . '</td>';

                           echo '<td width="200px">' . $row->stock . '</td>';    
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </table>
                        </thead>


                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

        </div>
```

This is my controller for my view. My struggle is that I don't know how will I change the number in the status column into image so that it will show whenever the status is 1 it shows an ok logo.

```
     public function itemlistadmin() {
                $check_session = $this->session->userdata('login');
                if(!isset($check_session)){
                    redirect('login/index','refresh');
                }

                $this->pagi();
                $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
                $user['user'] = $this->UserModel->userdata($username);
                $this->load->view('layout/header_admin', $user);
                $this->load->view('layout/footer_admin', $user);
                $this->load->model('ItemModel');
                $data['items'] = $this->ItemModel->getItems(5, $this->uri->segment(3));
                $data['page'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
                $msg = $this->session->userdata('msg');

                if(isset($msg)){
                    $data['msg'] = $msg;
                }
                $item_id = $this->session->userdata('item_id');
                if(isset($item_id)){
                    $this->session->unset_userdata('item_id');
                }
                $this->load->view('admin/item_view_admin', $data);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I may suggest, avoiding using *echo* in view files makes it a lot cleaner and easier to read, like such:

```
<?php foreach($items as $row): ?>
<tr class="active" height="60px">
    <td><?= $row->item_id ?></td>
    <td width="200px"><?= $row->item_name ?></td>
    <td width="200px"><?= $row->item_description ?></td>
    <td width="200px"><?= $row->serial_number ?></td>
    <td>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url("item/viewitemadmin/$row->item_id") ?>">
            <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="View Item"></span></h2>
        </a>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url("item/edititem/$row->item_id") ?>">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit Item"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url("item/item_delete/$row->item_id") ?>">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Item"></span>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td width="200px">
        <img src="<?php if ($row->stock) echo 'https://example.com/image.jpg' ?>" />
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    foreach($items as $row) { 

        if($row->stock == 1){
            $stock = 'Put the icon or text here when stock==1';
        }
        else{
            $stock = 'Put the icon or text here when stock==0';
        }

        echo '<tr class="active" height="60px">';
        echo '<td >' . $row->item_id . '</td>';
        echo '<td width="200px">' . $row->item_name . '</td>';
        echo '<td width="200px">' . $row->item_description . '</td>';
        echo '<td width="200px">' . $row->serial_number . '</td>';



        echo '<td >' . '<a href="'.base_url().'item/viewitemadmin/'.$row->item_id.'"><h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="View Item"></span></a>' . ' ';
        echo '<a href="'.base_url().'item/edititem/'.$row->item_id.'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit Item"></span></a>' . ' ';
        echo '<a href="'.base_url().'item/item_delete/'.$row->item_id.'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete Item"></span></a>' . '</td>';

           echo '<td width="200px">' . $stock . '</td>';    
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
```